# CakePHP 3.0 Timestamp behavior

Tags: cakephp, timestamp, cakephp-3.0, behavior

I would like to update a timestamp in a users table when a user logs in. I created a datetime field called 'lastLogin'.

From my users controller's login action I call:

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if ($user) {
     $this->Auth->setUser($user);
     $this->Users->touch($this->Users->get($user['id']), 'Users.afterLogin');
}
```

And in my Users table I have:

```
$this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
    'events' => [
        'Model.beforeSave' => [
            'created' => 'new',
            'modified' => 'always',
        ],
        'Users.afterLogin' => [
            'lastLogin' => 'always'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

I have tested that the event is triggered and entity property is being updated. However it is not saved to the database.

Is this intended, i.e. do I have to explicitly save the entity, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Andrius

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The behavior only updates the field

It isn't really clear from [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html#updating-timestamps-on-entities), but [the code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/ORM/Behavior/TimestampBehavior.php#L184-L198) only updates the field value. The behavior won't actually update the db, it's effectively assumed there would be a call to save later in the same request.

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 3.10 you can use the following (considering that `created` and `updated` are the two custom columns:

```
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
        'events' => [
            'Model.beforeSave' => [
                'created' => 'new',
                'updated' => 'always'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```